# Click command not working for with multiple controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two TextBox, one DatePicker, one ListBox  and one button in my view. I want to bind the values of the first three controls to ListBox on the button click.But when i clicked on the third textbox, the value of second textbox automatically added to the list (without button click). The same issue also exist for DatePicker.

**View**

```
<Grid>
    <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Customer1.Date, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="111,78,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Customer1.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Customer1.Name1, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="111,106,0,0"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.97,5.243" Margin="35,168,0,0" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}">
    </Button>
    <Label Content="{Binding Customer1.Name1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,231,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Customer1.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,269,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107"/>
    <Label Content="Scrum" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Standup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.105,0.591"/>
    <Label Content="Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.87,0.395"/>
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="347,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Customer1.Date}"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Customer1.Name1}"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Customer1.Name}"/>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
    public class CustomerViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        _Customer = new Customer();
    }
private Customer _Customer;
public Customer Customer1
{
get {return _Customer;}
}
private ICommand _clickCommand;
public ICommand ClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _clickCommand;
    }
    set
    {
        _clickCommand = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ClickCommand");

    }
}

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{

    PropertyChangedEventHandler Handler = PropertyChanged;

    if (Handler != null)
    {

        Handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }

}

#endregion
}
```

**Model**

```
    public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string _Name;
private string _Name1;
private string _Date;
public string Name
 {
 get{return _Name;}
 set
 {
 _Name=value;
 OnPropertyChanged("Name");
 }
 }
public string Name1
{
    get { return _Name1; }
    set
    {
        _Name1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name1");
    }
}
public string Date
{
    get { return _Date; }
    set
    {
        _Date = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Date");
    }
}
#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{

    PropertyChangedEventHandler Handler = PropertyChanged;

    if (Handler != null)
    {

        Handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }

}

#endregion


}
```

Note: I have set the datacontext to my viewmodel. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox` and `ListBoxItem` are bind to the same object. When one of them update the object, there is a `OnPropertyChanged`, and that's notify the UI to update. So if the text `TextBox` update `Customer1.Name`, `<ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Customer1.Name}"/>` will be update.

Whatever the button action !

The textbox update the object when it lost focus. You can change it with the binding property `ÙpdateSourceTrigger`

If you want to update `ListBox` only when you click on the button, may be you can bind on another object, and use a copy on the command action.

Comment: Since i am new to MVVM, can you please explain the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to implement [RelayCommand](http://snipplr.com/view/13642/) in your project.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
#region Fields

readonly Action<object> _execute;
readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;        

#endregion // Fields

#region Constructors

public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
: this(execute, null)
{
}

public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
{
    if (execute == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;           
}
#endregion // Constructors

#region ICommand Members

[DebuggerStepThrough]
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
}

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _execute(parameter);
}

 #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Change your `ICommand` Property as like below given & implement `CanCommandDo` & `CommandDo` events

```
    private ICommand _clickCommand;
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_clickCommand == null)
                _clickCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.DoMyCommand(p),p => this.CanDoMyCommand(p));
            return _clickCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool CanDoMyCommand(object p)
    {
        ////enable or disable your command here
        return true;
    }

    private object DoMyCommand(object p)
    {
        ////operations of command execution goes here.
        return null;
    }
```